# SOLR plugin to add field to response

Tags: plugins, solr

Usecase:
we have reservation prices that can differ from each date. So every record in SOLR contains a base_price + dynamic fields that exists of a day price containing the number of people, for example: base_price_2_20141231 = 30 <- reservation for 31 december 2014 for 2 persons is 30 euro. Now we want to show the total price and let the user sort on it.

Because the dynamic fields aren't always there we decided to make a custom plugin for SOLR so that this plugin would be able to detect if the dynamic fields are present or not and create a total price for the number of people and date rangers

My question at this moment is:
I'm overriding a SearchComponent for the above purpose, is this the best way to do it?
Are there any other ways (ownfieldtype, customfunction?) to do it and what are the pros/cons?

So what i need this plugin to do:

- acces all fields including dynamic fields in a document so i can calculate a total price
- Add this price to the same document and return it so we can display the price in our app.
- user should be able to sort on price

What i already found:

- http://www.searchbox.com/developing-a-solr-plugin/
- http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins
- and some other websites